# Creating a ASP.Net site with user added database entity types (editable)

Tags: asp.net

I have started out to build a web site in ASP.Net and are currently trying to wrap my head around some concepts. The site will display information on different kinds of rentable objects.
The biggest issue for me is that i want admin users to be able to add new types of objects without the need for a programmer to create infrastructure for them. I can't seem to find a tutorial which isn't based on a fixed database model with predefined entities.

For example:  Let's say an admin wanted to add bicycles as a new type of rentable object. After filling out a form, the database is updated with a new bicycle-table and its fields. Now the data model needs to be able to automatically integrate this table and generate appropriate (and editable) display views.
If someone could point me in a general direction of how this can be accomplished i would be really grateful. Is there a standard 'framework'-way of doing this or do i need to cook it up myself?

What i would like to do: Let admins create their own tables with custom fields and have the system connect these to a generic rentable_object table via a unique object id. When the site is viewed, the different types of objects are displayed in editable datatables - each with the generic properties first, followed by the specific.

Comment: You might consider using an [**EAV**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it seems like overkill for my scenario if i understand it correctly. I don't need a different database structure to be able to add an undefined number of fields. I have a object class 'rentableObject' with some fixed properties and want users to be able to create subclasses of this object type with their own set of properties.

Comment: Are there multiple "clients" using the same website and database?  What happens if two different admin users want to create their own versions of the `bicycle` object?

Comment: Well, no. It would be quite restricted. It would not be possible to create different database tables with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Granted, its in MVC but it I think that it's a tutorial well worth studying.

Comment: Thanks, but i wanted to avoid coding specific entity classes. I would like to give users the possibility to add new entity types.

Comment: oh I see. that's a totally different matter then. i can only think of custom ways for doing something like that which requires loads and loads of code :)

Comment: I was afraid of that... :/

Comment: You need to think of a way of introducing your own types which instead of data will actually hold data definitions. i can tell you from the get go that you will probably end up having an unreadable schema which will be very difficult to query (and slow if you have lots of rows)

Comment: I designed something similar back-in-the-day. Try and imagine the custom entities as lists, the data types that you will make available to the users as list-items and then a simple (but very long) table in which you will associate each row with the instance id and the data type-id which will hold all the values for those types...

Comment: Hmm, i guess that's something like what @mellamokb meant... (In comment to my question.)

Comment: What i would like to do: Let admins create their own tables with custom fields and have the system connect these to a generic rentable_object table via a unique object id. When the site is viewed, the different types of objects are displayed in editable datatables - each with the generic properties first, followed by the specific.